# Excel Criteria NB.SI.ENS

Tags: excel, vba, criteria

My data were: age
If my cell range : B2: B13
The corresponding age between "20" and "29"
I wish it count

Criteria "> 20 & < 29"

```
  =SOMMEPROD(NB.SI.ENS(INDIRECT("'"&{"DECEMBRE"."NOVEMBRE"."OCTOBRE"."SEPTEMBRE"."AOUT"."JUILLET"."JUIN"."MAI"."AVRIL"."MARS"."FEVRIER"."JANVIER"}&"'!" & {"D4:D13"."D4:D18"."D4:D18"."D4:D13"."D4:D26"."D4:D16"."D4:D24"."D4:D18"."D4:D15"."D4:D26"."D4:D24"."D4:D16"});**Criteria Sup of 20 AND Inf 29**))
```

Thanks you

Comment: Exemple : =NB.SI.ENS(D4:D17;> 20 & < 29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The criteria just need to be comma-separated (or whatever your local *list separator* character is) and specified in a string; `NB.SI.ENS` requires the range to be specified for each criteria, so this should work:

```
=SOMMEPROD(NB.SI.ENS(INDIRECT(...);">20";INDIRECT(...);"<29"))
```

Comment: Hello,
I get an error when using : =NB.SI.ENS(D4:D16;">20","<29")

Comment: @LongEttinger probably the comma I put there by mistake. Edited.

Comment: Ah, I mistaken `NB.SI.ENS` for `SOMME.SI.ENS` - you need to specify the *criteria range* for each criteria. It will be the same for both, you need to copy it.

Comment: My data were: age
If my cell range B2: B13
The corresponding age between "20" and "29"
I wish it count